# Do I need to grease, grease-proof paper?

Tags: baking

This feels like a very silly question, but I'm about to bake some american style cookies, and I wanted to know if I had to grease the grease-proof paper first, or if the idea was that 'grease' would come out of the stuff being baked?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to grease the paper. However, if you really want to, you can grease it, but beware that the bottom of your cookies can bake quicker due to the extra fat that transfers heat.

In most cookies, there is already a lot of fat which prevents them from sticking on their own.

Answer (score 3):

No. You'll find the cookies over-browned on the bottom, and spreading inconsistently if you do.